# Sync between database and domain layer

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have a general question about domain driven design. I have a place in my code where my database table schema is not the same as the domain object for it.

Let me give the scenario

```
Database table - 
EmployeeDepartment table has columns
1. DepartmentKey - (Integer Type)
2. DepartmentName - (Varchar)
3. FacilityName - (Varchar)

The C# domain class for it has the following 
1. Key (Integer)
2. DepartmentName (String)
3. FacilityName (Sting)
4. Employees (IList<Employees>)
```

In this case, there is a gap between database design and domain design for the same entity. In the DB - I use a bridge table to access list of employees in a group. But in the C# code I use a IList to access the list of Employees.

I want to know

1. If this a good design. Do experts in Domain Driven Development have a way around this gap?
2. I can foresee problems by going on designing like this. Would enforcing a test for mappings help?

Comment: What do you mean by bridge table? You mean that it is many to many relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a place in my code where my database table schema is not the
>   same as the domain object for it.

Welcome to the object-relational [impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) :)

It's a classical problem that can be solved using an object/relational mapping framework.

Domain driven design being a domain-first approach, it's perfectly normal to have that kind of mismatch. Just design your aggregates and entities as you see fit without worrying about the database at first. Then create the relational model. Chances are it won't be a one-to-one match between tables and entities, this is where an ORM is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong with your design. If you choose two different types of objects I would recommend to use Automapper to map these two objects. For more information on that one check the following link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper

AND: you should ALWAYS use unit tests to verify the functionality of your code! Even better would be to apply test driven development because there you have to write code in order to realize your logic. But this is my opinion!

Greetings